# -[UIView adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in ios 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, scrollview

[image]> Scrollview have content view to manage subviews,

> Error comes in ios 11 work fine in ios 10
>
> -[UIView adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10296d680 2017-10-02 12:34:11.931454+0530
>   MobifinX1_Subscriber[1235:135465] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x10296d680'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x186f53d38 0x186468528 0x186f611f8 0x19071bcc4 0x186f596e4 0x186e3f0dc 0x1906f2628 0x1906f23f0
>   0x1906f1bc0 0x1906f18f0 0x19040c964 0x1904e8e48 0x19040ae04
>   0x19040aa34 0x19040a95c 0x190361000 0x18af310b4 0x18af35194
>   0x18aea3f24 0x18aeca340 0x1905c7744 0x190ca6718 0x190c9f574
>   0x186efc358 0x186efc2d8 0x186efbb60 0x186ef9738 0x186e1a2d8
>   0x188cabf84 0x1903c7880 0x100abcb5c 0x18693e56c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Add more code please or show your storyboard file.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Now you can see it clearly.

Comment: Somewhere you think that you are managing a `UIScrollView` object where in fact it's a `UIView` object, so it doesn't responds to `-adjustedContentInset` and causes the crash.

Comment: I just remove contentScrollView(UIView)'s iBOutlet now its working. actually i didn't get it, what is reason behind it?.

Comment: I got it, We can not IBOutlet of UIView subview of scrollView with named contentScrollView. thanks for support friends

Comment: @RaviHMalviya in that case, may you post a self-answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Answer - we can not take iboulet of uiview inside uiscrollview with named contentScrollView.