# When Navigate to the specific UIViewcontroller across any event the App is Crashing in iOS 11 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, navigation

When I Navigate the specific UITableView called "InvoiceViewController" from HomeViewController by didSelectRowAtIndexPath and from "TimerViewController" by sliding Slider Action. App Crashing and the compiler, throwing following error.

```
2017-10-30 14:57:25.181311+0400 FixtrProvider[3667:1496216] desc: -[UIView adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102d16010
2017-10-30 14:57:25.181369+0400 FixtrProvider[3667:1496216] name: NSInvalidArgumentException
2017-10-30 14:57:25.181402+0400 FixtrProvider[3667:1496216] user info: (null)
2017-10-30 14:57:25.181466+0400 FixtrProvider[3667:1496216] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView adjustedContentInset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102d16010'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18575fd38 0x184c74528 0x18576d1f8 0x18ef27cc4 0x1857656e4 0x18564b0dc 0x18eefe628 0x18eefe3f0 0x18eefdbc0 0x18eefd8f0 0x18ec18964 0x18ecf4e48 0x18ec16e04 0x18ec16a34 0x18ec1695c 0x18eb6d000 0x18973d0b4 0x189741194 0x1896aff24 0x1896d6340 0x18eb62884 0x1857078b8 0x185705270 0x18570582c 0x1856262d8 0x1874b7f84 0x18ebd3880 0x100e6a47c 0x18514a56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Properties of the invoiceViewController
[image: Invoice properties]
[image: Invoice Scene]
Please help me to find out the issue that caused only in iOS 11 devices.

Comment: Seem like you have same problem with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520992/uiview-adjustedcontentinset-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-ios-11

Comment: @trungduc Yes, exactly same..

Comment: Show name of properties in your `InvoiceViewController`

Comment: ok, wait I will edit the post shortly..

Comment: @trungduc Editted the post, Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename `contentScrollView` in `line 28` to another name or remove outlet.

Comment: I removed the contentScrollView outlet and it solved the issue.. Thanks!

Comment: can you answer this question another similar ios 11 only issue of mine.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889903/ios-11-only-crash-issue-when-i-tap-a-tab-bar-app-is-crashing)

Comment: I have commented on your other question. Please take a look.